# Java - violation of Liskov substitution principle?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I have the following code:

```
interface Ops{
    void remove();
}

interface BeforeRemove{
    void doBeforeRemove();
}

class A implements Ops{
    @Override
    public void remove() {
        System.out.println("REMOVED A");
    }
}

class B implements Ops, BeforeRemove{
    @Override
    public void remove() {
        System.out.println("REMOVED B");
    }

    @Override
    public void doBeforeRemove() {
        System.out.println("SOMETHING TO DO BEFORE REMOVE");
    }
}

public class Proba2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Ops> ops = List.of(new A(), new B());
        for(Ops o : ops){
            if(o instanceof BeforeRemove br){   //is this a bad thing to do?
                br.doBeforeRemove();
            }
            o.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this cast to `BeforeRemove` violation of the Liskov substitution principle? If yes - why so? I read somewhere that the only time that we can cast to some type is when we know that that is going to be of that type, but compiler doesn't know. Here neither I nor the compiler know.

The other alternative would be to move that `doBeforeRemove` method to `Ops` - but then possibly I would have a lot of empty methods - that also does not seem right to me.

Comment: You're not doing anything that violates the LSP in this case. However, it could easily lead to violations later if an object suddenly requires `doBeforeRemove()` to be called before `remove()`, even though `Ops` says the object should be removable without such a call. Have you considered using `default` methods in your interface?

Comment: I mean, here in theory most OOP way would be to use Visitor pattern and have different implementation for `Ops, BeforeRemove` and `Ops`, but that would complicate things a bit. I just wanted to ask about `instanceof`, since I read that it is a code smell when using OOP.

Comment: If `B extends A implements BeforeRemove` and B's `remove()` requires `doBeforeRemove()` to be called first, then it violates the LSP because it can no longer stand in for A. However, right now it's just a code smell and not a LSP violation. I would definitely say that empty methods is a cleaner and more suitable approach though. It's not ugly or tedious since you haven't had to actually write the unused methods since Java 8, and even before that, you had abstract classes to simplify it.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic May I ask why you need `doBeforeRemove` here? The `Ops` implementor would know when `remove` is called already and so is the client. What problem are you trying to solve? Having both operations forces the client to know in which order they should be called which is not very appealing.

Comment: @plalx yes, I guess here `doBeforeRemove` should probably be hidden behind `remove`. It was more of a question that I remembered that `instanceof` is a code smell, but then wanted to see what could be done in this situation - like alternative of adding base empty method which is also not ideal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSP refers to the behavior of subclass & superclass (or interface & implementation). It doesn't refer to the usage itself, meaning that the way you use these classes has no bearing on LSP, only the definition of the classes does.

Therefore, the code in your question does not violate LSP.

That said, `instanceof` is a "design smell". As noted by @that other guy, it can be eliminated using Java 8's default method:

```
interface Ops {
    void remove();

    default void doBeforeRemove() {}
}

class A implements Ops{
    @Override
    public void remove() {
        System.out.println("REMOVED A");
    }
}

class B implements Ops {
    @Override
    public void remove() {
        System.out.println("REMOVED B");
    }

    @Override
    public void doBeforeRemove() {
        System.out.println("SOMETHING TO DO BEFORE REMOVE");
    }
}

public class Proba2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Ops> ops = List.of(new A(), new B());
        for(Ops o : ops){
            br.doBeforeRemove();
            o.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dislike that the client is responsible for knowing that `doBeforeRemove` should be called before `remove` though.

Comment: True, without any context it doesn't seem like `doBeforeRemove()` should be an API.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, this example is not a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.

But satisfying the LSP is not the reason that OOP discourages type checking such as `instanceof`. OOP's most powerful feature is polymorphism, and type checking is the antithesis of polymorphism. Relying on `instanceof` shows the API is not designed to take advantage of OOP. You can redesign an API to favor OOP, but you can also consider alternative programming paradigms that focus less on polymorphism.

In summary, the LSP is not the primary goal of OOP.